# Is there a name for this variation of the strategy pattern?

Tags: design-patterns

A strategy class is applied depending when a certain condition is met. The strategy is 'chosen' as it were.  Strategy pattern 101.

But what if there is a group of classes that are all applied based on the same condition. Conceptually, you can point to the group of classes and call the whole group the strategy, but that relationship is not explicit and more to the point, the logic inside those classes are isolated precisely so they don't know each other. They just happen to invoke on the same condition.

Example:

```java
public interface BookValidator {
    enum PublishType { PAPER_BACK, HARD_COVER, EPUB }

    PublishType validationFor();
    boolean validate(Book book);
}

class HardcoverBookBindingValidator implements BookValidator {
    public PublishType validationFor() { return PublishType.HARD_COVER; }
    public boolean validate(Book book) { /* perform validation */ }
}

class HardCoverPaperqualityValidator implements BookValidator {
    public PublishType validationFor() { return PublishType.HARD_COVER; }
    public boolean validate(Book book) { /* perform validation */ }
}

class EpubSectionsValidator implements BookValidator {
    public PublishType validationFor() { return PublishType.EPUB; }
    public boolean validate(Book book) { /* perform validation */ }
}

class EpubIndexValidator implements BookValidator {
    public PublishType validationFor() { return PublishType.EPUB; }
    public boolean validate(Book book) { /* perform validation */ }
}

// etc.

public boolean validateBook(Book book) {
    for (BookValidator validator: allBookValidators) {
        if (validator.validationFor() == book.type() && !validator.validate(book)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

I see this approach a lot, is there a name for this? I'm leaning towards Strategy Pattern with a simple separation of concerns applied to it (SRP, high cohesion), but I'm not sure.

A common similar approach using Spring specifically is to have a super type for all publish types and then have Spring [inject them](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/beans.html#beans-autowired-annotation) into collections for each type. Basically a glorified factory. The point is: there is no single strategy object, unless you count the collection of objects for a specific type the strategy.

Comment: @Héctor, added.

Comment: I see a quite standard implementation of Strategy Pattern in your example. About "the same condition", it could be inside a factory so you don't have to loop but return an instance of required validator given a book.

Comment: @Héctor, indeed (or have super classes for each type and then have Spring inject all beans of that type). It's a common idiom.

Comment: It sounds like your doing a Strategy pattern into Facade.